# Converting.tif files to shapefiles

Tags: raster, shapefile, geotiff-tiff

I have received multiple tif. files like roads, forest_dis_scaled, grass_dis_scaled. I am trying to create a useful map for the study area but I am not sure if it is even possible to convert these files to shapes and use it on a map. I have tried raster to polygon but it didn't the results I was looking for.

Comment: Please read up on the fundamental differences between raster and vector data, and how to convert them into each other.

Comment: You had tags for QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop but did not mention which you are using in your question body so I removed them.

Comment: I added both since I use both of them for most analysis and it wouldn't have been a problem if I get the answers in ArcGis or QGIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplistic view that works 90% of the time is that vectors are optimal for categorical data and rasters are optimal for continuous data. So you should think twice before converting your data if you you have continuous values in your rasters.

That being said, based on the few information provided, I can guess that the problem of conversion is because you have to many different values. You could simplify your data (with some loss of information) by reclassifying your tiff file (using, "reclassify" from spatial analysis extension, or some map algebra) before you convert it to polygons (with raster to polygon).